# Sound compression books

Tags: audio, signal-processing, voice

What books about sound (speech) compression and vocoder construction do you recommend?

I should to create voice coder and I need your help. Thanks for attention.

Comment: You might get better feedback on http://avp.stackexchange.com or http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you're new to signal processing, you may want to start with something simple like [G.711](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711)'s A- and μ-law compression, then ADPCM like in [G.726](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.726), and only then go for more advanced things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What books about sound (speech) compression and vocoder construction do you recommend?
>   I should to create voice coder and I need your help. Thanks for attention.

Let me get this straight, you want to create a dynamics compressor and vocoder?

Here are a collection of links that would be useful:

- [Synth Secrets](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm), articles on synthesis
- [(Synth Secrets)Vocoder](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jul00/articles/synthsec.htm), article on the workings of a vocoder
- [Collection of Audio-DSP algorithms](http://www.musicdsp.org/)

As for books, try [Applied Speech and Audio Processing: with MATLAB examples](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Speech-Audio-Processing-Examples/dp/0521519543/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325040027&sr=8-1).

---

If on the other hand you meant data-compression for vocals (as it is quite difficult to determine which one), then try [Introduction to Data Compression (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Multimedia Information and Systems)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Compression-Kaufmann-Multimedia-Information/dp/012620862X/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1325040152&sr=1-6).

Comment: Thank you:) Did you have any experience in creating vocoder? What language did you use?

Comment: I haven't created a vocoder, but I typically code in C and C++ and the links I provided give you details on how to go about creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still print: "Voice and speech processing' by Thomas Parsons. ISBN 0-07-048541-0. If you search for this book in Google books you'll quickly find related/equivalent works.